# How can I make the contents of a <section> have a width of zero?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<section id="sidebar" class="grid_3">
<section id="content" class="grid_9">
```

I used jQuery to change this to:

```
<section id="sidebar" class="" style="width: 0px;">
<section id="content" class="grid_12">
```

However it seems like the section with id of sidebar still has some width and the elements inside it appear.

Is there some way that I can make the contents of id=sidebar just not visible using jQuery? I thought giving it a width of 0px would make it work but it seems not to. What I was wondering about was setting the display to hidden or visibility but I am not sure of the differences between hidden and visible? Also not sure about the jQuery show and hidden. Which would be best in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#sidebar").hide() // sets the position of the element to `display: none`;
$("#sidebar").show() // sets the position of the element to `display: block`;
$("#sidebar").css('width', '0 !important') // sets the width of the element to `0` and overrides other element's width properties;
$("#sidebar").css('visibility', 'hidden') // The element is invisible but still takes up space;
```

> `how can I detect if the display is set to "none" with jQuery?`

try this:

```
if ($('.grid_3').is(':hidden')) { // if the element is hidden do something here}
if ($('.grid_3').is(':visible')) { // if the element is visible do something here}
```

Comment: This seems to work but how can I detect if the display is set to "none" with jQuery? Previously I was using "if ($("#sidebar").width() == 0)".

Comment: @Anne edit: you have changed your comment try this: `if ($('.grid_3').is(':hidden')) { // do something here}`

Answer (score 1):

`visibility: hidden` hides the element but stays in the document flow. `display: none` will hide and remove the element from the regular flow. `opacity: 0` can be used in other cases. Another option used in some circumstances is to `position: absolute` the element and hide it by shifting it to one side with `left: -9999px`. Choose one of those options, `width: 0` simply doesn't fit in any scenario, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#sidebar').hide()` will hide the sidebar, BUT you have to be aware (as @elclanrs explains) that this removes that element from the document flow, so if the presence of the sidebar is necessary for your layout to work, use `$('#sidebar').css('visibility', 'none')`.

Answer (score 0):

As other pointed:

- `visibility: hidden;`: hides the element and its content but keeps taking space (just like setting `opacity: 0;`);
- `display: none;`: hides the object and remove it from the flow, freeing the space for other elements (eg.: if you set this on an element above, the elements below will move up to take its space);

To set the element with a width of zero and hide the content you need to set the `overflow` property to `hidden`

- `overflow: hidden`: hides the content that overflows (expand beyond the border of its parent), preventing it from apearing outside its parent.

With jQuery, I recoment using `animate()` to make the task:

```
$("#sidebar").css("overflow", "hidden").animate({ width: "hide" }, "fast");
```

you can use "toggle" or "show" here as the width parameter.